# Using subquery result for inner join

Tags: python, sql, subquery, inner-join

I have two tables. i want to filter out rows from table `class` then take that filtered table and join it with `books` to compare two columns of this new table (`orderid` from class table and `order_id` from books table). whenever these two columns matches , i want to select that row. i have tried this

```
query = """ select col1 , col2 , col3 from class 
INNER JOIN books
ON class.order_id = books.orderid 
IN (SELECT orderid from books where name=%s and lastname=%s ); """
```

my tables have thousands of rows so it takes very long to execute. is there any better solution?

Comment: You miss `WHERE books.orderid` before the IN I'd say

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `col1, col2, col3` comes from table `calss` then you can use `exists`

```
select col1 , col2 , col3 
from class c
WHERE exists 
(
  SELECT 
    orderid 
  from books b
  where c.order_id = b.orderid 
  and name=%s 
  and lastname=%s 
)
```

Other option is to select `orderId` in sub-query

```
select col1 , col2 , col3 
from class c
INNER JOIN (SELECT orderid from books where name=%s and lastname=%s) b
ON c.order_id = b.orderid
```

Otherwise you can use your original query where you are missing `where`

```
select col1 , col2 , col3 
from class 
INNER JOIN books
ON class.order_id = books.orderid 
WHERE orderid IN (
  SELECT orderid from books where name=%s and lastname=%s 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not firstly filter out the book table, then join this smaller filtered table with class table?

```
select col1 , col2 , col3 
from class c
inner join (select * from book where where name=%s and lastname=%s) b
on c.order_id = b.orderid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this query with IN, or EXISTS or make a JOIN.
I would suggest you try JOIN. It depends on the actual DBMS, the query optimizer and you data distribution, existence of indexes etc, but from my experience if it is possible to use INNER join, that construct works faster.
But it is also important that you make sure you have indexes on the columns you join on (filter by), so both of these:

> class.order_id = books.orderid

but also:

> books.name and books.lastname

Perhaps the index on the last name would be enough, then the rows with the same last name would have to be scanned to find matching first names.

Which DBMS are you using? Usually there is a way to check the query execution plan, and you can see which parts are slow. For example `"EXPLAIN SELECT ..."` in MySQL.

Artur